# How to use whatever to define a point on a segment?

Tags: metapost

The point M is such that the line (CM) is perpendicular to the line (NP).
I do not understand the error of this code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
path carre, p;
carre = unitsquare scaled 138;

pair a, b, c, d, N, P, M;
a = point 0 of carre;
b = point 1 of carre;
c = point 2 of carre;
d = point 3 of carre;

p = b -- d;
N = whatever[a,d];
P = whatever[a,b];
M = whatever[b,d];
(M - c) dotprod (P - N) = 0;

draw M -- c;

draw p  withcolor blue;
draw carre withcolor red;

label.lft("$A$", point 0 of carre);
label.lrt("$B$", point 1 of carre);
label.urt("$C$", point 2 of carre);
label.ulft("$D$", point 3 of carre);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the error.  Please try to trim your example down to the minimal that reproduces that error.  And please try to give a more meaningful title so that it's possible to get here through an internet search.

Comment: @Fabrice The problem is that you don't give sufficient information about what you want to do. It would work if MetaPost would know where N and P are, but you only specify that they are anywhere on a line. That's not nearly enough to determine  their position, so the line between them isn't well-defined.

Comment: M is a point on the diagonal [BD]. Points N and P are such that APMN is a rectangle. The lines (CM) and (PN) are perpendicular. I try this `N = whatever[a,d];
  P = whatever[a,b];
  M = whatever[b,d];
  (M - N) dotprod (a -d)=0;
  (M - P) dotprod (a -b)=0;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, and so that this has an answer: `whatever` can be used wherever `metapost` can uniquely assign it a value by solving linear equations.  You were getting an error because `M` cannot be uniquely determined from the given information.  For example, here are two possible positions for `M`:

[image]

Both `N` and `P` must be specified in order to uniquely determine `M` (note that specifying only one is still not enough).  In this case, `metapost` is able to find its location (see code at end).  Regarding your comment:

> M is a point on the diagonal [BD]. Points N and P are such that APMN
>   is a rectangle. The lines (CM) and (PN) are perpendicular. I try this
>   N = whatever[a,d]; P = whatever[a,b]; M = whatever[b,d]; (M - N)
>   dotprod (a -d)=0; (M - P) dotprod (a -b)=0;

If I read your comment correctly, it is true that lines CM and PN are orthogonal/perpendicular for every choice of `M` (observe that the shaded triangles below are similar).  As such, the criteria do not uniquely specify `M` and `metapost` is unable to assign it a location.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

path carre, p;
carre = unitsquare scaled 138;

pair a, b, c, d, N, P, M, Q;
a = point 0 of carre;
b = point 1 of carre;
c = point 2 of carre;
d = point 3 of carre;

beginfig(1);
% fix N
N=.07[a,d]; 
% fix P
P=.3[a,b];


p = b -- d;
% M is a point on the line through b and d
M = whatever[b,d];
% such that the line through M and c is orthogonal 
% to the line through P and N.  Since this point is unique
% (and the constraints are linear) metapost can find it.
(M - c) dotprod (P - N) = 0;

% to extend the line through M and c to intersect with the
% line through N and P: find the point Q that is both on 
% the line through M and c and on the line through N and P.
% This point is unique so metapost can find it.
Q=whatever[M,c]=whatever[N,P];
draw N--P dashed evenly;
draw M -- c;
dotlabel.rt("$M$",M);
draw M--Q dashed evenly;
draw P--Q dashed evenly;
draw unitsquare scaled 5 rotated angle(c-M) shifted Q;


draw p  withcolor blue;
draw carre withcolor red;

label.lft("$A$", point 0 of carre);
label.lrt("$B$", point 1 of carre);
label.urt("$C$", point 2 of carre);
label.ulft("$D$", point 3 of carre);
dotlabel.bot("$P$",P);
dotlabel.urt("$N$",N);
endfig;

% regarding comment
beginfig(2);
M := .6[b,d];
N := (0,ypart M);
P := (xpart M,0);

Q:=whatever[c,M]=whatever[N,P];
fill M--Q--N--cycle withcolor .8;
fill a--N--P--cycle withcolor .9;
fill M--(xpart b, ypart M)--c--cycle withcolor .95;
draw M--N;
draw M--P;
draw N--P dashed evenly;

draw c--M--Q;
draw unitsquare scaled 5;

draw p  withcolor blue;
draw carre withcolor red;

label.lft("$A$", point 0 of carre);
label.lrt("$B$", point 1 of carre);
label.urt("$C$", point 2 of carre);
label.ulft("$D$", point 3 of carre);
label.lft("N",N);
label.bot("P",P);
label.top("M",M);
label.bot("Q",Q);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for these very clear explanations